# loop over dictionary object in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a dictionary userData of type string object.
I make an http call to get data.

```cs
internal static Dictionary<string, object> userData = null;

userData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(httpData);
```

structure of userData is something like this

```json
{
    "id": "12345",
    "class": [
        "my-user",
        "college-student"
    ],
    "list": [
        {
            "a": "CSE",
            "b": "DataBase"
        },
        {
            "a": "IT",
            "b": "ComputerNetwork"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i have to iterate over this userData to retrieve value of a and b.
Can please someone help me to do so in c#

Comment: You can be helped as soon as you post any attempt you have made and describe what isn't working.

Comment: Probably be simpler to deserialize the data into a class that reflects the data (instead of something generic like you seem to be attempting).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way with the code your currently have:

```
var arr = (JArray)userData["list"];

foreach (JObject item in arr) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("a: {0}", item["a"]);
    Console.WriteLine("b: {0}", item["b"]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The value in the `userData` for key `"list"` is a `JArray` of `JObject`s, each containing an `"a"` and `"b"` property.

However, another (better) way would be to create a few classes that represent your JSON structure:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> @Class { get; set; }
    public List<ListItem> List { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize into an instance of `MyClass` instead:

```
var userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

foreach (ListItem item in userData.List)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a: {0}", item.A);
    Console.WriteLine("b: {0}", item.B);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I tried one with foreach loop. Its working fine. Thanks for your help